# Error with \hline and similar commands

Tags: rules, line

I am a beginner of LaTex. TeXstudio informs me about this error: "I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case."

My text is

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}    
\noindent
\textbf{bla bla} bla bla.). \hline

\end{document}
```

It draws the line as I requested, but it indicates also the error above.
The same is if I insert `\toprule`, `\midrule` or `\bottomrule` in place of `\hline`

Comment: `\hline` is for tables. Use `\hrule` instead.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx!  `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`, all from `booktabs`, are also for tables. They are effectively improved versions of `\hline`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is that you are not in a tabular environment. `\hline` and the `booktabs` commands are for those environments only and LaTeX will throw the error you get if you use them anywhere else.

You could use `\hrulefill` instead. Or even `\rule{width}{height}` where you would specify the parameters width and height as lengths (such as `12pt`).